# Paginator URL won't work with custom route (returns 302 instead)

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x, paginator

In my CakePHP 3.3 app, I use a custom route for the categories controller. It routes all traffic to the view action.

On that specific page I use the Paginator component, but when I render the Paginator URLs the URLs won't work. When I click the URL, it will be 302  redirected to the homepage instead.

This is my route:

```
<?php $routes->connect('/categories/**', ['controller' => 'Categories', 'action' => 'view']); ?>
```

I use this code to render the sort link:

```
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('popularity', 'most popular'); ?>
```

Which generates this (correct) url:

```
http://example.com/categories/15-rugzakken?sort=popularity&direction=asc
```

When I call that URL, it 302 redirect me to the homepage (/) instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action

Comment: What does your controller code look like? And why are you using '/categories/**' and not the greedy 1 star? '/categories/*'

Comment: I've tested it with one star, which didn't work.

Controller code:
`$products = $this->paginate(
    $this->Categories
     ->find( 'all' )
     ->matching(
      'Products', function ( $q ) use ( $productWhere ) {
      return $q->where( $productWhere );
     } )
     ->matching( 'Shops.Currencies' )
     ->where( [
      'Categories.id'      => $id,
      'Categories.shop_id' => $this->shop_info->id
     ] )
     ->group( 'Products.id' )
   );`